# send UIAlert from background mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently using local notification to indicate incoming call from background mode. That's works fine, but this is what i see, when skype got a call in background mode:

[image]

So looks like it possible to show UIAlert from background and anybody can answer me how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can not display an `UIAlertView` from the background, but you can scheudule a [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Just set the [`fireDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW2) property of the [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the current date and it will be displayed directly.

Comment: But what about the [important table](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) in class reference?

Comment: @Cojoj That is unrelated.  It just means that the alerts will still be there when your application comes back if you don't dismiss them before going into the background.

Comment: Oh, okey, I get it :)